# Using Boost test detect_memory_leaks option on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, boost, memory-leaks

I am currently trying to use the `detect_memory_leaks` option with boost on my mac (OS: el capitan 10.11.3). So far, everytime I executed my test binary with the option `--detect_memory_leaks=1`, no matter how much I leak, boost doesn’t complain. If you want to reproduce my problem, here is a way to reproduce:

I’m using boost 1.59 version and compile the unit test framework as static libraries. Then, I create two sample programs:

main.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test module name
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( TestSuiteSample )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( TestCaseSample )
{
    int * a = new int[3];  // This will leak memory, boost should complain
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

I compile my binary the following way:

```
g++ -I../boost_1_59_0 -L../boost_1_59_0/stage/lib -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_chrono -lboost_prg_exec_monitor -lboost_system -lboost_test_exec_monitor -lboost_timer -lboost_unit_test_framework main.cpp test.cpp
```

As you can see, I’ve included all the boost libraries generated when compiling boost/test but using `-lboost_unit_test_framework` only compiles fine also.

Now I have an executable `a.out` that I launch this way:

```
./a.out --detect_memory_leaks=1 --log_level=all --report_level=detailed
```

and I get the following result:

```
Running 1 test case...
Entering test module "test module name"
test.cpp:3: Entering test suite "TestSuiteSample"
test.cpp:5: Entering test case "TestCaseSample"
test.cpp:8: info: check true has passed
test.cpp:5: Leaving test case "TestCaseSample"; testing time: 60us
test.cpp:3: Leaving test suite "TestSuiteSample"; testing time: 82us
Leaving test module "test module name"; testing time: 105us

Test module "test module name" has passed with:
  1 test case out of 1 passed
  1 assertion out of 1 passed

  Test suite "TestSuiteSample" has passed with:
    1 test case out of 1 passed
    1 assertion out of 1 passed

    Test case "TestSuiteSample/TestCaseSample" has passed with:
      1 assertion out of 1 passed
```

As you can see, there is no complaint from boost about the `new int[3]` I didn’t delete. At first, I thought it was the compiler that optimizes the code and don’t even allocate my variable, but valgrind sees a leak as `definitely lost`:

```
==2571==    by 0x10004E5BD: TestSuiteSample::TestCaseSample::test_method() (test.cpp:7)
```

I don’t get what I’m doing wrong but if anyone knows how to get the error generated by the leak in test.cpp, I’d be glad to know it. I tried several ways to call the option and tried to figure out what to do in the boost documentation, but so far, nothing seems to work.

Help is welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation [[1]](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost/debug/detect_memory_leaks.html) [[2]](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/rt_param_reference/detect_memory_leaks.html) (emphasis mine):

> On platforms where memory leak detection is possible inside of running application **(at the moment this is only Windows family)** you can switch this feature on and off using this interface.

Since you're on a Mac and building with g++, it won't do anything.